# Checkboxes alignment issues in Struts2

Tags: html, css, jsp, checkbox, struts2

Im displaying the checkboxes with header along with values using the Struts2 checkbox as below:

```
<table id="incentiveTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center; padding: 7px;">     
                Marketing Incentive
            </th>
            <th colspan="1" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center; padding: 7px;">     
                Advertizing Incentive
            </th>
            <th colspan="1" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center; padding: 7px;">     
                ChannelPlacement Incentive
            </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator status="stat" value="incentiveList">
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.marketingIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.advertizingIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.channelPlacementIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the checkboxes not aligned properly:

[image]

I need headers to be `Marketing Incentive` , `Advertizing Incentive` and `ChannelPlacement Incentive` adjance to the checkboxes

I have used above code but it doesnt work

I have further modified the code as

```
<table id="incentiveTable">
                <thead>
                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            Marketing Incentive
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            Advertizing Incentive
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            Advertizing Incentive
                                    </td>
                            </tr>   
                        <s:iterator status="stat" value="incentiveList">
                            <tr>
                                
                                    <td>
                                    <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#incentiveList.marketingIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    
                                <td>
                                    <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#incentiveList.advertizingIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
                                </td>
                                
                                
                                <td>
                                    <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#incentiveList.channelPlacementIncentive}]"  theme="simple" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
                    
                    <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the o/p is as shown in the second image
[image]

please suggest the alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generated by your tags is not valid HTML.

Since you've used `theme="simple"`, no extra mark-up will be generated, and you need to handle it on your own, by manually creating the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags around your checkboxes:

```
<tbody>
    <s:iterator status="stat" value="incentiveList">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}].marketingIncentive"  theme="simple" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}].advertizingIncentive"  theme="simple" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}].channelPlacementIncentive"  theme="simple" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</tbody>
```

EDIT: there was also an error with the IteratorStatus usage, now corrected.

For this to work BTW you need to make sure `checkboxes` is the name of the source list too, other than the target one, otherwise you need to use the `value` attribute too.